# Both firefox and chromium have problem with loading webpages

Tags: internet

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and always up to date. My Internet speed is good. When I download something, it downloads with a good speed. But in case of browsing, not a single page load completely in both browser. There is always a moving wheel. Some websites take more than 5 minutes to load.(Google analytics) If there is a slider in the web-page, the slider doesn't load. On tab, the moving wheel is moving. 
Please help....

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your internet connection starting either with your router and or broadband modem as both browsers are taking a long time to load. The alternative could be that it's something with your Ubuntu installatoin. You could try Google.com to see how fast that page loads for starters (it should load within seconds if that long even). In Ubuntu there is also a application called "Network Tools". When you open it, there should be a tab called "Traceroute". Enter "google.com" (without the quotations") and trace it. The times shown are in milliseconds and are shown beside each waypoint your computer takes to find Google.com. Times over "200", I'd say, may show where you have a trouble spot. The first waypoint should be your computer with the next being either your router or modem and then your ISP and so on.

Comment: I'd say either the OP has routing issues or DNS issues. Either way, it's not a web browser problem, especially if *two different engines* exhibit the same behavior. `host` and `traceroute` are of help here. Anyway, I'd guess the ISP is to blame.